# Is there there a way to view the values of all bound emacs variables matching a prefix?

Tags: variables, emacs, settings, show

For example, I would like to know the values of all variables with prefix "comint-*"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to get customizable variables, then you can use <kbd>M-x customize-apropos</kbd>.

Otherwise, try something like this:

```
(with-output-to-temp-buffer "*Variables*"
  (set-buffer standard-output)
  (insert (mapconcat (lambda (sym) (format "%s: %s" sym (eval sym)))
                     (apropos-internal "^comint-.*" 'boundp) "\n\n")))
```

That'll produce a `*Variables*` buffer with contents like:

```
comint-accum-marker: nil

comint-buffer-maximum-size: 1024

comint-completion-addsuffix: t
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Not "perfect" but you could do <kbd>C-h</kbd> <kbd>v</kbd> `prefix` and then hit <kbd>tab</kbd> to get all the variables that start with that `prefix.

If you want to try it out manually, the function you need to dig into is `completion--do-completion`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I'd do it:

```
(require 'cl)
(loop for sym being the symbols
      when (and (boundp sym) (string-match "^comint-" (symbol-name sym)))
      collect (cons sym (symbol-value sym)))
```

On my system, this evaluates to:

```
((comint-output-filter-functions comint-watch-for-password-prompt)
 (comint-mode-abbrev-table . [ 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0])
 (comint-exec-hook (lambda nil (set-process-query-on-exit-flag ... nil)))
 (comint-file-name-prefix . ""))
```

Comment: Hi Sean - I am curious about the mechanism behind this. Even after (require 'cl) symbols is not bound.  So is this ability to loop over the symbol table embedded within the loop macro?  I couldn't find this documented (even though it works as you describe).

Comment: Yes, the loop macro handles clauses of the form "being the" specially.  Other possibilities are "being the frames" (to iterate over all of the visible frames) and "being the buffers" (to iterate over all buffers).  See: http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/cl.html#For-Clauses for more complete information.